# Evaluation of model without training of model in the execution of cnn in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am new to pytorch as I have just started today, I saw few examples in kaggle and try to adapt my cnn from tensorflow in torch to enable better gpu allocation.

I want to balance the data in train and test dataset so I have used train_test_split. I have two problems:

1. I could not evaluate the model before training the model. I want to just see the val_loss and val_accuracy without training the model. But that is not possible
2. I was just testing for 2 epoch but the validation accuracy shows abnormal value, why is it so?

Could someone help please?

I have defined the customdataset in other python file and importing it in the main module

```
import os
import cv2
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
import torch.optim as optim
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision
from torchsummary import summary

class CustomDataset(Dataset):

        def __init__(self, root_folder_path):

            self.root_folder_path = root_folder_path
            self.image_files = []
            self.labels = []


            # Collect image paths and corresponding labels

            folders = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(root_folder_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(root_folder_path, f))])
            self.label_dict = {folder: i for i, folder in enumerate(folders)}


            for folder in folders:

                folder_path = os.path.join(root_folder_path, folder)
                image_files = sorted([f for f in os.listdir(folder_path) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(folder_path, f)) and f.endswith('.jpg')])
                self.image_files.extend([os.path.join(folder_path, img) for img in image_files])
                self.labels.extend([self.label_dict[folder]] * len(image_files))


            self.transform = transforms.Compose([
                transforms.ToPILImage(),
                transforms.Resize((900, 300)),
                transforms.Grayscale(),
                transforms.ToTensor(),
                transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.5], std=[0.5])
            ])

            

        def __len__(self):

            return len(self.image_files)


        def __getitem__(self, idx):

            image_path = self.image_files[idx]
            label = self.labels[idx]
            image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
            image = self.transform(image)
            #print("Image shape:", image.shape)  # Print the shape of the image
            one_hot_label = torch.zeros(len(self.label_dict))
            one_hot_label[label] = 1

            return image, one_hot_label
```

this is my main script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    
    # Instantiate your custom dataset and dataloaders
    root_folder_path = r'W:\MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH\THESIS\code and dataset\image_dataset_300_900_10_classes'
    dataset = CustomDataset(root_folder_path)

    print("Labels:", sorted(dataset.label_dict.keys()))
    print("Total number of labels:", len(dataset.label_dict))


    # Display some images from each folder
    n_images_to_display = 4
    n_folders = len(dataset.label_dict)
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(n_images_to_display, n_folders, figsize=(n_folders * 4, n_images_to_display * 4))

    for i, (folder, label) in enumerate(dataset.label_dict.items()):
        folder_images = [dataset[i][0] for i, lbl in enumerate(dataset.labels) if lbl == label]
        indices_to_display = random.sample(range(len(folder_images)), min(n_images_to_display, len(folder_images)))
        for j, ind in enumerate(indices_to_display):
            ax[j, i].imshow(folder_images[ind].squeeze(), cmap='gray')  # Squeeze to remove the channel dimension for grayscale images
            ax[j, i].axis('off')
        ax[0, i].set_title(folder, fontsize=30)

    plt.show()
    fig.tight_layout(pad=0, w_pad=0, h_pad=0)

  

    from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Subset
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    TEST_SIZE = 0.2
    BATCH_SIZE = 64
    SEED = 42

    # Get the labels from the dataset
    labels = np.array([label for _, label in dataset])
    

    # generate indices: instead of the actual data we pass in integers instead
    train_indices, test_indices, _, _ = train_test_split(
        range(len(dataset)),
        labels,
        stratify=labels,
        test_size=TEST_SIZE,
        random_state=SEED
    )

    # generate subset based on indices
    train_split = Subset(dataset, train_indices)
    test_split = Subset(dataset, test_indices)
    print('Length of train_batch:',len(train_split))
    print('Length of test_batch:',len(test_split))

   
    # create batches
    train_loader = DataLoader(train_split, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, num_workers=6,shuffle=True,pin_memory=True)
    test_loader = DataLoader(test_split, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,num_workers=6,pin_memory=True)

    class ImageClassificationBase(nn.Module):
        
        def training_step(self, batch):
            images, labels = batch 
            out = self(images)                  # Generate predictions
            loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels) # Calculate loss
            return loss
        
        def accuracy(self,outputs, labels):
            #_, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
            preds = torch.argmax(outputs, dim=1)
            preds_one_hot = F.one_hot(preds, num_classes=labels.shape[1])  # Convert predictions to one-hot encoding
            print("Shape of preds:", preds_one_hot.shape)  # Check the shape of preds
            return torch.sum(preds_one_hot == labels).float().mean()                 
           
        
        
        
        def validation_step(self, batch):
            images, labels = batch 
            out = self(images)                    # Generate predictions
            loss = F.cross_entropy(out, labels)   # Calculate loss
            acc = self.accuracy(out, labels)           # Calculate accuracy
            return {'val_loss': loss.detach(), 'val_acc': acc}
            
        def validation_epoch_end(self, outputs):
            batch_losses = [x['val_loss'] for x in outputs]
            epoch_loss = torch.stack(batch_losses).mean()   # Combine losses
            batch_accs = [x['val_acc'] for x in outputs]
            epoch_acc = torch.stack(batch_accs).mean()      # Combine accuracies
            return {'val_loss': epoch_loss.item(), 'val_acc': epoch_acc.item()}
        
        def epoch_end(self, epoch, result):
            print("Epoch [{}], train_loss: {:.4f}, val_loss: {:.4f}, val_acc: {:.4f}".format(
                epoch, result['train_loss'], result['val_loss'], result['val_acc']))

    import torch.nn.init as init
    class ImageClassification(ImageClassificationBase):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.network = nn.Sequential(
                #image size is [1,900,300] as [channel, height,width]
                nn.Conv2d(1, 32, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
                nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),

                nn.Conv2d(32,32, kernel_size = 3,  padding = 1),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
                nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            
                nn.Conv2d(32, 64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
                nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
            
                nn.Conv2d(64 ,64, kernel_size = 3, padding = 1),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
                nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
                nn.AvgPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2),
                                    
                nn.Flatten(),
                nn.Dropout(0.3),

                nn.Linear(64 * 56 * 18, 64),  # Assuming input size after convolutional layers is 64 * 56 * 18
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
                nn.Dropout(0.2),
            
                nn.Linear(64, 64),
                nn.LeakyReLU(0.01),
                nn.BatchNorm1d(64),
                nn.Dropout(0.2),
            
                nn.Linear(64, 10)  # Output layer
            )
            # Initialize the weights of convolutional layers
            self._initialize_weights()

        def _initialize_weights(self):
            for m in self.modules():
                if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
                    init.kaiming_uniform_(m.weight, mode='fan_in', nonlinearity='leaky_relu')
        
        def forward(self, xb):
            return self.network(xb)

    def get_default_device():
        """ Set Device to GPU or CPU"""
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            return torch.device('cuda')
        else:
            return torch.device('cpu')
        

    def to_device(data, device):
        "Move data to the device"
        if isinstance(data,(list,tuple)):
            return [to_device(x,device) for x in data]
        return data.to(device,non_blocking = True)

    class DeviceDataLoader():
        """ Wrap a dataloader to move data to a device """
        
        def __init__(self, dl, device):
            self.dl = dl
            self.device = device
        
        def __iter__(self):
            """ Yield a batch of data after moving it to device"""
            for b in self.dl:
                yield to_device(b,self.device)
                
        def __len__(self):
            """ Number of batches """
            return len(self.dl)

    device = get_default_device()
    device

    torch.cuda.empty_cache()
    model = ImageClassification()

    random_seed = 99
    torch.manual_seed(random_seed)

    train_loader = DeviceDataLoader(train_loader, device)
    test_loader = DeviceDataLoader(test_loader, device)

    to_device(model, device)

    @torch.no_grad()
    def evaluate(model, val_loader):
        model.eval()
        outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
        return model.validation_epoch_end(outputs)

    def accuracy(outputs, labels):
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
        return torch.tensor(torch.sum(preds == labels).item() / len(preds))

    def fit(epochs, lr, model, train_loader, val_loader, opt_func=torch.optim.RMSprop):
        history = []
        optimizer = opt_func(model.parameters(), lr)
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            # Training Phase 
            model.train()
            train_losses = []
            for batch in train_loader:
                loss = model.training_step(batch)
                train_losses.append(loss)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
                optimizer.zero_grad()
            # Validation phase
            result = evaluate(model, val_loader)
            result['train_loss'] = torch.stack(train_losses).mean().item()
            model.epoch_end(epoch, result)
            history.append(result)
        return history

    model=to_device(ImageClassification(),device)

    #initial evaluation of the model
    evaluate(model,test_loader)

 #set the no. of epochs, optimizer funtion and learning rate
    num_epochs = 2
    opt_func = torch.optim.RMSprop
    lr = 0.0001

    #fitting the model on training data and record the result after each epoch
    history = fit(num_epochs, lr, model, train_loader, test_loader, opt_func)
```

data looks like this and my size of the image in the model is [1,900,300] where 1 stands for graychannel, 900 - height of the image in pixels, 300 - width of the image in pixels

[Sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Hpi.jpg)

and the output is:

```
  Labels: ['120', '144', '168', '192', '216', '24', '240', '48', '72', '96']
Total number of labels: 10
Length of train_batch: 1835
Length of test_batch: 459
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Train batch size: torch.Size([11, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([11, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([32, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([32, 10])
Test batch size: torch.Size([11, 1, 900, 300])
Shape of labels array: torch.Size([11, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([11, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([11, 10])
Epoch [0], train_loss: 1.5568, val_loss: 1.6037, val_acc: 267.2000
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32, 10])
Shape of preds: torch.Size([11, 10])
Epoch [1], train_loss: 0.9959, val_loss: 1.6849, val_acc: 273.4667
```

Here is the drive link for the dataset: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PsT9_HWX4snfgnhlwC6xM4rNjcoqXdk5?usp=drive_link

As @Ivan suggested, I have tried but error is still there
output of the code

```
PS C:\Users\smjobagc> & C:/Users/smjobagc/AppData/Local/miniconda3/envs/FSV/python.exe "w:/MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH/THESIS/code and dataset/10 class cropped 300_900 runs/10_class_torch.py"
Labels: ['120', '144', '168', '192', '216', '24', '240', '48', '72', '96']
Total number of labels: 10
Length of train_batch: 1835
Length of test_batch: 459
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "w:\MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH\THESIS\code and dataset\10 class cropped 300_900 runs\10_class_torch.py", line 236, in <module>
    evaluate(model,test_loader)
  File "C:\Users\smjobagc\AppData\Local\miniconda3\envs\FSV\lib\site-packages\torch\autograd\grad_mode.py", line 28, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "w:\MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH\THESIS\code and dataset\10 class cropped 300_900 runs\10_class_torch.py", line 206, in evaluate
    outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
  File "w:\MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH\THESIS\code and dataset\10 class cropped 300_900 runs\10_class_torch.py", line 206, in <listcomp>
    outputs = [model.validation_step(batch) for batch in val_loader]
  File "w:\MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH\THESIS\code and dataset\10 class cropped 300_900 runs\10_class_torch.py", line 92, in validation_step
    acc = accuracy(out, labels)           # Calculate accuracy
  File "w:\MASTER_BAGCHI_SCHALDACH\THESIS\code and dataset\10 class cropped 300_900 runs\10_class_torch.py", line 212, in accuracy
    return torch.sum(preds.argmax(1) == labels).float().mean()
IndexError: Dimension out of range (expected to be in range of [-1, 0], but got 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laying out the situation may help you:

- a data loader outputting tensors of shape `(64, 1, 900, 300)`, *ie.* on 900 by 300 grayscale image per batch element;
- and the corresponding ground truth label of shape `(64,)`;
- a model which outputs class logits of shape `(64, 10)`, *ie.* `10` logits per batch element: `q1`, `q2`, ..., `q10`;
- you are trying to compare two tensors of different shapes: `preds == labels`, preds is `(64, 10)` while `labels` is `(64,)`.

Hence the error, which you can rewrite as

> The size of tensor **`labels`** (`64`) must match the size of tensor **`preds`** (`10`) at non-singleton dimension `1`

You're trying to compare the estimated probability of the image with an integer class, how can you expect this to work? You must first get the arg max of the estimated logits (*ie.* the class number associated with the highest scoring logit), ***only then*** will it make sense to compare with the ground truth to measure the accuracy:

```
(preds.argmax(1) == labels).float().mean()
```

Comment: Thankyou @Ivan for the reply. Unfortunately, the problem is still there. I have posted the error in the question above.

Comment: What are the shapes of `preds` and `labels` just before this line?

Comment: i chose batch size as 16
Shape of labels tensor: torch.Size([16, 10])
i think I cannot see the shape of **preds**

Comment: How come, you should look at the shape of `preds`, otherwise you won't know what the problem is!

Comment: i am sorry @Ivan, I thought since it is giving error at the accuracy so it won't print the shape of preds
Shape of preds: torch.Size([32])

Comment: So if `preds` is 1D, you don't need to apply the `argmax`. Why is `labels` shaped `(16, 10)`, what does it contain? Are you sure you haven't swapped them around? This new error message you get suggest that the argmax has already been applied.

Comment: oh, i was checking for different batch size(16/32) so labels shape is [batch_size,num_classes] and preds shape is 1D but it should be also equal to the shape of labels, right? any idea, how to implement it?

Comment: Are you labels one hot encoding?

Comment: Thankyou very much @Ivan for the help. Yes, I have onehotencoded the labels so I changed the preds shape to be equal to labels. But now, I could not evaluate the model without training of model first and even the validation accuracy is showing some abnormal results. Could you please help? Do I have to post another question for that?

Comment: No worries, consider accepting the answer as valid (green checkmark on the left). You can create a new thread, just ping me here so I can have a look.

Comment: Thankyou @Ivan for the help. Although I am trying by my own first, if I do not get then I will surely post a thread.